# The code "npm-run-eject' is not working for me on my react-native app on Windows 11. What should I do?

Tags: node.js, react-native

I am experiencing difficulty with the 'npm run eject' command on my React Native application, which is running on Windows 11. As a beginner, I am unclear about the issue and how to resolve it. Whenever I run the command, it does not seem to be functioning properly.

I attempted to run the 'npm-run-eject' command on Command Prompt, following the instructions listed on various websites. However, it returned an error message which said:

`npm ERR! Missing script: "eject" npm ERR! npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run: npm ERR! npm run npm ERR!  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in # C:\Users\Keerthana\AppData\Local\npm-cache\logs_\2024-03-24T06_36_27_392Z-debug-0.log`

What are my options to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check package.json file in the root of your project. Under "scripts" field it needs to have "eject". "npm run" can only run things listed under "scripts".